# Implementing Handlers the basic way

Tags: android, android-handler

I have this sample application on handlers which fires a Log at a certain time, but its seems to be not working when i clicked my start button. Below is my code.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private long selectedTimeInMills;
    private Handler handler;
    private static final Calendar CALENDAR = Calendar.getInstance();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TimePicker timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        final TextView timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        handler = new Handler();
        String textTime = formatDate(CALENDAR.getTimeInMillis(), "hh:mm a");
        timeText.setText(textTime);

        timepicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {

            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                CALENDAR.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                CALENDAR.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                selectedTimeInMills = CALENDAR.getTimeInMillis();
                String textTime = formatDate(CALENDAR.getTimeInMillis(), "hh:mm a");
                timeText.setText(textTime);
            }
        });

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Runnable runnable =  new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("HandlerCheck", "Handler Fired! @ ("+selectedTimeInMills+") "+formatDate(selectedTimeInMills, "hh:mm a"));
                    }
                };
                boolean flag = handler.postAtTime(runnable, selectedTimeInMills);

                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Handler is Fired?:: "+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        });

    }
}
```

NOTE: When I clicked on my button and it implement the `handler.postAtTime()` it returns `true` but still it won't display the Log on DDMS even though i've set my timepicker 1 min from the current time still won't fire the Log message on DDMS

Comment: Are you seeing any errors / exceptions in logcat?

Comment: nope nothings got displayed nothing really happens after that selectedtime passes

Comment: OK, just thought of something. Make sure you don't have a mismatch of the hour between 12 hour and 24 hour clocks, e.g., 3 in the afternoon  (12 hour) is 15 (24 hour). Try logging what is being passed into `onTimeChanged(...)` just to check.

Comment: hmm onTimeChanged always have a 24 format so 3pm is 15, tried also using the System.currenttimeinmills and added 20secs to postAtTime still nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`postAtTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postAtTime%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method in `Handler` class takes in the time in milliseconds from the statup; not the `Calendar` time (which is what you are passing). You should be using `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` to calculate the time instead.

Alternatively, you can use `postDelayed` function to invoke the Runnable object after a set time period (in milliseconds).

```
// Introduce a new private variable
private long delayedTimeInMillis;

// Update delayedTimeInMillis inside onTimeChanged method:
delayedTimeInMillis = selectedTimeInMills - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

// replace handler.postAtTime(runnable, selectedTimeInMills); line with this:
handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayedTimeInMillis)
```

Comment: ohhh so thats what the upTimeMills, i have a hunch that this was the problem, but also i thought of maybe this is the same mills as all the other time utils in adnroid and java.. hmm gonna try this out

Comment: Btw @thira im confused with postDelayed and postAtTime.. cuz i wan't to fire the handler at a certain time not delay it at a certain time, can u enlighten me?

Comment: @lemoncodes : Using the `delayedTimeInMillis` approach suggested by Thira should work. I hadn't realised `postAtTime` used the time since boot.

Comment: yep it worked fine, but i have a trouble analyzing on how am i going to use postDelayed in my app where i want to fire something at a certain time not delay it...

Comment: @lemoncodes from my experience, they both accomplish the same task; which is to execute the Runnable after a set period of time. The only difference is the reference point and how you calculate the time. For example, `postAtTime` is calculated with your phone's boot time as the starting point (so if you specify 60000 ms the handler will invoke it 60s after booting your phone provided you start the app immediately).

Comment: @Thira so for short its not really applicable when im gonna use my handler to fire an alarm?.. cuz i need it to be accurate down to the minute only so to avoid delay, cuz if i gonna be implementing with down to the seconds firing an alarm might get delayed